# Is it possible to enter Adam Kadmon and retain your individuality?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, practical-kabbalah, breslov

The Breslov Center has Pirkei Avos in English with commentary from Rabbi Noson and Rabbi Nachman. In the very first section it says the whole purpose of this world is to enable us to make a Yechida and yet retain our individuality by means of the tzadik.

I have some difficulty with this claim. Is this even possible? How can one become one with the En Sof and yet still retain their individuality?

Comment: In the same way (lhavdil) we can become one with our spouse and still retain our individuality. It's called face-to-face oneness, vs back-to-back, in the sources. Ish Echad, B'Lev Echad!